# ApplicationUser Object is not loading in a many to many relation

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, automapper

I am trying to learn asp.net core and I am trying to implement a reddit like website.

what I am trying to do is when a subreddit is called, I want to load both admins and the members of the that particular subreddit and pass them to viewmodel.

to achieve this i have made two tables

```
public class MemberSubReddit
{
    public long SubRedditId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubReddit SubReddit { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
// the names differ since I was trying to check if the problem is from naming conventions
public class AdminSubReddit
{
    public long SubRedditId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubReddit SubReddit { get; set; }

    public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
```

now when I execute this code below:

```
var sub = _subRedditRepository.GetSingle(e => e.Name == name, s => s.Posts, s => s.Admins, s => s.Members);
```

the SubRedditId and SubReddit object loads in both admins and members, but as for User object only the UserId(AspNetUserId) loads and the ApplicationUser do not load.

also this is my modelbuilder code (based on asp.net core website in entityframework core, many to many connections are not handled automatically and you have to do it manually):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AdminSubReddit>()
             .HasKey(t => new { t.SubRedditId, t.AspNetUsersId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MemberSubReddit>()
             .HasKey(t => new { t.SubRedditId, t.UserId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<MemberSubReddit>()
            .HasOne(us => us.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(ms => ms.MemberIn)
            .HasForeignKey(us => us.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MemberSubReddit>()
            .HasOne(ms => ms.SubReddit)
            .WithMany(ms => ms.Members)
            .HasForeignKey(ms => ms.SubRedditId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AdminSubReddit>()
            .HasOne(us => us.AspNetUsers)
            .WithMany(ms => ms.AdminIn)
            .HasForeignKey(us => us.AspNetUsersId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AdminSubReddit>()
            .HasOne(ms => ms.SubReddit)
            .WithMany(ms => ms.Admins)
            .HasForeignKey(ms => ms.SubRedditId);
```

so please tell me what I am doing wrong :D
also since I am new to this if you can see any structural problem with the code I would be happy if you point them out.

**EDIT**

```
public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

This is the method which is getting called in the controller

Comment: Could you post  `_subRedditRepository` content?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question